# How to use HTML to do a Skype call?

Tags: html, skype

I tried to insert the following snippet in my script. By clicking the link it should do a call to a Skype account. I've been looking for hours now, but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

> `<pre><code>&lt;a href=&quot;callTo://USERNAME&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://goodies.skype.com/graphics/skypeme_btn_small_green.gif&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</code></pre>`

Is it accepted in any way or do I miss something here?

Comment: Do you have skype installed?? http://www.ehow.com/how_2008799_use-skype-links.html

Comment: Aye. Hm. That was the reason why I was asking. Ty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create application link to Skype profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177332/create-application-link-to-skype-profile)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try "callto" (with no uppercase letters).

```
<a href="callto://+***********">Link will initiate Skype to call my number!</a>

<a href="skype:********?call">Link will initiate Skype
   to call my Skype username!</a>
```

source: http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2010/03/create-html-link-that-starts-a-skype-call/

Comment: Well, when clicking that link nothing happens. I tried to create a sample link <a href="#"> which worked really fine.

Comment: Did you try both callto: with the number and skype: with the username?

Comment: Yes. I also tried the get-a-skype-button method. In every case the link wasn't linked. Even if I had not installed Skype there must've been a link...

Comment: Also, try in different browsers. I don't use skype so I cannot test this myself. In Firefox, go Tools > Options..., then in the Application tab, find "skype" or "callto" and check if those are associated with the Skype application.

Comment: Well, Skype isn't running in my browser. I wasn't able to find skype or callto in my application tab. But does it make any difference when the link is no link? Forgot to try the other browsers ic. I'll be right back. Tried it with three different browsers. Same result

Comment: When you say "the link is not a link" do you mean that when you add that code to your page, it doesn't actually display a clickable link? Or that it does create a clickable link, but clicking on it doesn't do what you expect it to?

Comment: i have tried this for the username, it does not work. it opens new page saying `The address wasn't understood`

Answer (score 14):

I have been fighting with the following link all day.

```
<a href="skype:USERNAME?chat">Start chat</a>
```

The problem that I had was with the **USERNAME** part

Finally, I just solved it.

My name on Skype web page was **name** but the real name was **name lastname**. The link in my web page ***did make*** Skype to load in my Android phone but, Skype failed to find the account to wich I wanted to call (name lastname).

I tryed, and failed:

```
<a href="skype:name lastname?call">...
<a href="skype:name+lastname?call">...
<a href="skype:name%20lastname?call">...
<a href="skype:name-lastname?call">...
<a href="skype:name_lastname?call">...
<a href="skype:phonenumber?call">...
```

Then, the solution:

```
<a href="skype:live:emailnamewithoutdomain?call">...
```

I just hope u find it usefull.

And, do not forget that u have a plenty of commands to add after the **?** in the url (add,call,chat,and so on).

Comment: For Chat Option :
<a href="skype:echo123?chat">Chat/Use Can use Image in-place of this</a>
Demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/zl5jQoJbvi2l4ppcztAW/preview

Answer (score 1):

Just for another option from their official website:
https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons

It's nice and easy to use, can be used both for chat or/and call.

[image]