# Create application link to Skype profile

Tags: html, hyperlink, skype

I'd like to create an application link in HTML to a Skype profile. I've found that you can do the following:

```
<a href="skype:profile_name">Link to my profile</a>
```

But this seems to trigger a Skype call to that profile. I'd just want the option to browse the profile or add them as a contact, how can I do this?

Comment: Related: [Add Skype contact in Gmail signature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/70337/22759)

Answer (score 194, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be very well documented, but there are ways to specify an action for a Skype profile link. This is the syntax

```
skype:profile_name?action
```

Examples of such actions are

- `call` to call
- `chat` to chat
- `voicemail` to leave a voice mail
- `sendfile` to send a file
- `add` to add to contacts
- `userinfo` to view profile

In this case then, the link to view the profile would look like this

```
<a href="skype:profile_name?userinfo">Link to my profile</a>
```

See also the [Skype URIs page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745878.aspx).

Comment: @vrunoa If your signatures are HTML, I don't see why not. Best way would be to try it out ;-)

Comment: @vrunoa you can use url shortners to make http:// link that leads to your link "skype:profile_name?userinfo". And this http:// link will work great in any mail signature. Even in GMail. But not all shortners will work properly. Just tested it with http://is.gd/ and it works great!

Comment: Creating above link and clicking it works as expected, but for some reason, I cannot just enter it in the Chrome bar. [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/) tells me that it is not a valid URL (even if I add double slashes behind the colon). I am still trying to find a way of easily sharing my Skype info via instant messenger.

Comment: @Domi, have you tried using a URL shortener like Vanger suggested?

Comment: @AlexTurpin I used goo.gl as mentioned above. I also tried bitly.com. Both complain about invalid URLs.

Comment: Plunker Demo :http://embed.plnkr.co/zl5jQoJbvi2l4ppcztAW/
Skype Documentations
http://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-buttons/create-skype-buttons/

Comment: @AlexTurpin I know this answer is old, it still works fine. But if the user is not logged-in, skype fails to launch when the user info link is clicked.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Good to know, not much we can do about that but feel free to add it to the answer.

Comment: Dear @AlexTurpin what should be the solution when a user not logged in skype & click on the skype.If not logged in then how we set this that skype launch for log in.Thank You.

Comment: @vrunoa you just saved my butt.. I was working on a platform that appends http:// to every link. Which in turn breaks the Skype URI. But the URL-shortener worked like a charm! All for a silly Skype social icon...