# Link to Skype profile fails

Tags: html, hyperlink, skype

I am trying to create a link from my website to my skype profile. I saw this post by Alex Turpin [Create application link to Skype profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177332/4323504). This works fine, When skype link is clicked it goes straight to my skype profile.

However if the skype link(`<a href="skype:profile_name?userinfo">Link to my profile</a>`) is clicked while the user is not logged-in skype, this fails(skype client crash).

So I removed 'userinfo' from this link(`<a href="skype:profile_name?">`) and tried again, Skype did not fail, it asked me to login, but after that it made a skype call instead of viewing the profile.

How can I resolve this? How to view a skype profile succesfully while user is not loggged-in skype.

Thanks.

Comment: anyone with the answer???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid this is Skype's problem, it happens on all Skype versions. I reported this issue to them.

For now we can try a work-around(like Marin suggested in the answer below).

The following actions still works even if a user is not logged-in skype, try using one of them until we get a proper solution for this issue.

- `<a href="skype:profile_name?call">Text</a>` to call
- `<a href="skype:profile_name?chat">Text</a>` to chat
- `<a href="skype:profile_name?voicemail">Text</a>` to leave a voice mail
- `<a href="skype:profile_name?sendfile">Text</a>` to send a file
- `<a href="skype:profile_name?add">Text</a>` to add to contacts

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite intriguing.


The problem could be in Skype version or in Skype in general (or windows?). I've tested it with my current version which is 7.3.0.101 on Windows 8.1 and it's crashes as you said. You can report this to Skype support, but untill this is fixed (or you find any solution), I suggest you to try some workaround like

`<a href="skype:profile_name?chat">Link to my profile</a>`

Or you can try whatever action you like, but I think `chat` for now would be OK.

Comment: I will try some work-around until I find a solution for this issue...thanks for your suggestion Marin