# The phone number in websites

Tags: html, phone-number

In my website I have a page contact us and it has a phone number. I want to click on it from my mobile smart phone so the dial of the number appear so I don't need to copy it and paste to dial the number.

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855650/using-html-to-do-a-skype-call) about Skype tags too.

Answer (score 1):

Use tel: in html anchor tag.

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```